# How do I connect a monitor and mouse to a computer a long distance away?

Tags: display, mouse

I want to put a brain computer with cameras in 1 spot than have another one away from it at least a good 20m, with a monitor and mouse. How can I tend to do it? and what wires

Comment: A common name for such a device is a `KVM Extender`.

Comment: Lots of clarification would be nice - I assume that a brain computer is not a brain in a jar - what is is? How are the cameras connected hw/software wise? What's the other system? Are they networked? Stuff like this is *essential* in understanding your problem

Answer (score 1):

For a distance of about 20m, you could use active signal-boosting cables, available for USB (mouse) and HDMI (monitor). These cables tend to cost far more than their passive counterparts, but can reach far greater distances.

For even longer distances, this may not be sufficient. The standards and protocols involved were not designed to deal with the issues arising from a longer cable: increased latency and increased interference. In this case, the best (and likely cheapest) solution would be to add a second low-power computer where you want the display to be, and connect the two with a network cable. You can then use remote control software to access the more powerful primary computer. Ethernet (cat5e/cat6) can reach 100m without further boosting, and can easily extend beyond that if necessary.